# When the form is re-displayed - often the "password" field is blank. Why?

Tags: web, passwords, theory, form-submit

There's a strange tradition to ask user to re-enter his password when the registration form has failed the validation.

E.g. the CAPTCHA value was wrong and now the *password* field is empty: users have to re-enter it.

What's the reason for that? Is it really that unsafe to put the password back to the input, even through HTTPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a value in the password input field would require it being in plain text in the html source.

Comment: So? Is user input in that field more secure against JS scripts than in the source or what?

Comment: No, JS would always be able to grab the value of any text entered into the password field. I think the risk here is that all source html gets saved to a temp directory on your computers hard drive for some amount of time.